# Webpack injecting some text into a site

Tags: webpack, internationalization

I want to provide alternate text for the UK and Us versions on my site

The first thing I want to do  I want to do is change the title

```
<title>This is the US version</title>
<title>This is the UK version</title>
```

Then I could change the intro

```
    <h1>Hello from the UK</h1>
or 
    <h1>Greetings from the US</h1>
```

Is this possible from within Webpack to pick a text file. I don't really need full internationalization I just need to be able to pick a text file based on the build.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that using [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)

from the [docs](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates):

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    title: 'Custom template',
    // Load a custom template (lodash by default)
    template: 'index.html'
  })
]
```